# Distinct not working in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am trying to get the data for the distinct emplid field from PS_Z_EXS251AE_EMP table and insert it into PS_Z_EXS253AE_EMP along with a number of empty values.  But when I run the below it gives me an error saying 'missing expression'.  If I remove the keyword 'distinct' it runs (but duplicate emplids are inserted).  Can someone please help me only insert unique emplids...

```
insert into PS_Z_EXS253AE_SSO 
(Z_RESERVED41, Z_SSN, Z_RESERVED38, Z_REC_TYPE_ID, Z_RESERVED11, Z_IDP_NAME_ID, Z_OPERATION_CODE, Z_RESERVED40)
select ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', distinct(z_emplid_exs), ' ', ' ' 
from ps_z_exs251ae_emp
where asofdate in( to_date('2015/01/06','yyyy/mm/dd'), to_date('2015/01/05','yyyy/mm/dd') );
```

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. Please read the manual

Answer (score 3):

Distinct is for whole row and not just for one column. Try this

```
insert into PS_Z_EXS253AE_SSO 
(Z_RESERVED41, Z_SSN, Z_RESERVED38, Z_REC_TYPE_ID, Z_RESERVED11, Z_IDP_NAME_ID, Z_OPERATION_CODE, Z_RESERVED40)
select distinct ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', z_emplid_exs, ' ', ' ' 
from ps_z_exs251ae_emp
where asofdate in( to_date('2015/01/06','yyyy/mm/dd'), to_date('2015/01/05','yyyy/mm/dd') );
```